# Split Sublime Text 3 plugin into separate Python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want to develop a ST3 plugin that requires a larger amount of logic. In order to keep the code readable, I want to split the logic and ST-related party into different files (Python modules).

If I create a new directory for my Sublime Text plugin, containing two files, plugin.py and othermod.py (empty), and insert the following content into plugin.py

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import othermod

#my plugin code here
```

the Sublime console outputs

> ImportError: No module named 'othermod'

and the *plugin.py* file is skipped.

Is there any way to import *othermod* from within my *plugin.py*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **need** a file called `__init__.py` in the same directory as your other files. Exactly *why* you need `__init__.py` is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Also, just to be on the safe side, make sure that you've actually saved both of the files. Sometimes you need to restart Sublime before it'll recognize your file as a module.